# calculated columns in new datatable without altering the original

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
set.seed(43)
dt <- data.table(
    a = rnorm(10),
    b = rnorm(10),
    c = rnorm(10),
    d = rnorm(10),
    e = sample(c("x","y"),10,replace = T),
    f=sample(c("t","s"),10,replace = T)
    )
```

i need (for example) a count of negative values in columns 1:4 for each value of e, f. The result would have to look like this:

```
   e neg_a_count neg_b_count neg_c_count neg_d_count
1: x           6           3           5           3
2: y           2           1           3          NA
1: s           4           2           3           1
2: t           4           2           5           2
```

Here's my code:

```
for (k in 5:6) { #these are the *by* columns
 for (i in 1:4) {#these are the columns whose negative values i'm counting
   n=paste("neg",names(dt[,i,with=F]),"count","by",names(dt[,k,with=F]),sep="_")
   dt[dt[[i]]<0, (n):=.N, by=names(dt[,k,with=F])]
  }
}

dcast(unique(melt(dt[,5:14], id=1, measure=3:6))[!is.na(value),],e~variable)
dcast(unique(melt(dt[,5:14], id=2, measure=7:10))[!is.na(value),],f~variable)
```

which obviously produces two tables, not one:

```
   e neg_a_count_by_e neg_b_count_by_e neg_c_count_by_e neg_d_count_by_e
   1: x                6                3                5             3
   2: y                2                1                3             NA

   f neg_a_count_by_f neg_b_count_by_f neg_c_count_by_f neg_d_count_by_f
   1: s                4                2                3             1
   2: t                4                2                5             2
```

and need to be rbind to produce one table.
This approach modifies dt by adding eight additional columns (4 data columns x 2 *by* columns), and the counts related to the levels of e and f get recycled (as expected). I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to achieve the result, one which does not modify dt. Also, casting after melting seems inefficient, there should be a better way, especially since my dataset has several e and f-like columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only two grouping columns, we could do an `rbindlist` after grouping by them separately

```
rbindlist(list(dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x < 0)) , .(e), .SDcols = a:d], 
  dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x < 0)) , .(f), .SDcols = a:d]))
#   e a b c d
#1: y 2 1 3 0
#2: x 6 3 5 3
#3: s 4 2 3 1
#4: t 4 2 5 2
```

---

Or make it more dynamic by looping through the grouping column names

```
rbindlist(lapply(c('e', 'f'), function(x) dt[, lapply(.SD, 
           function(.x) sum(.x < 0)), by = x, .SDcols = a:d]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can melt before aggregating as follows:

```
cols <- c("a","b","c", "d")
melt(dt, id.vars=cols)[, 
    lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x < 0)), by=value, .SDcols=cols]
```